# Clear a list after adding its elements to another list

Tags: java, list

I'm doing a program that gets as parameter more sentences. And I made 2 lists, one called "propozitie", which contains each sentence, and one called "propozitii", which contains all sentences.

The problem is: When I clear the "propozitie" list after it meets a ".", it also clears the "propozitii" list and it's ending up by printing 3 empty lists.

Input data:

> Andrei goes there. Andrei plays football. I enjoy staying home.

Can anybody help me ? 
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Propozitie {

private static List<List<String>> propozitii;
private static List<String> propozitie;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    propozitii = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    propozitie = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String arg : args) {
        propozitie.add(arg);

        if (arg.contains(".")) {
            propozitii.add(propozitie);
            propozitie.clear();
        }

    }

    System.out.println(propozitii);

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, the statement

`propozitii.add(propozitie);`

adds the reference to propozitie to propozitii list. A copy of the object is not added. To do a copy, use this.

`propozitii.add(new ArrayList<String>(propozitie));`

now you can clear **propozitie**

Comment: Great. It would help the community if you accept the answer that worked. Others might try to skip the question or read the answered question to provide a better answer!